# PyTest warning in dj_rest_auth- RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.conf.urls.url() is deprecated in favor of django.urls.re_path()

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, pytest

When I'm using pytest to run test cases I'm getting 10 warnings -

```
RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.conf.urls.url() is deprecated in favor of django.urls.re_path().
    url(r'^password/reset/$', PasswordResetView.as_view(),
RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.conf.urls.url() is deprecated in favor of django.urls.re_path().
    url(r'^password/reset/confirm/$', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.conf.urls.url() is deprecated in favor of django.urls.re_path().
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='rest_login'),
```

There are 10 warnings like this. I've already tried filterwarnings in setup.cfg. The source of the error is: `C:\Users\suraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dj_rest_auth\registration\urls`

Edited-
this warning solved but now i'm getting the error to dj-rest-auth
[ImproperlyConfigured at /api/v1/auth/registration/account-email-verification-sent/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75469593/improperlyconfigured-at-api-v1-auth-registration-account-email-verification-sen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon checking the [source code](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/blame/d28afeae53105f92b66a6286070c8bdd013921aa/dj_rest_auth/urls.py#L13), I can see that the newer version of **dj_rest_auth** no longer uses url, but uses path.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # URLs that do not require a session or valid token
    path('password/reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='rest_password_reset'),
    path('password/reset/confirm/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='rest_password_reset_confirm'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='rest_login'),
    # URLs that require a user to be logged in with a valid session / token.
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='rest_logout'),
    path('user/', UserDetailsView.as_view(), name='rest_user_details'),
    path('password/change/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='rest_password_change'),
]
```

So updating **dj_rest_auth** to a newer version will fix the issue. See [release](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/releases) page for the version to choose from.

Comment: thanks, but yeah i know that, but that old one urlpattern is in inside dj-rest_auth package, not in my projects urls. location of package urls.py is  C:\Users\suraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dj_rest_auth\registration\urls

Comment: thanks man. i already did that, after my above comment it clicks me that i should update the package and that solved it.

Comment: Cheers! I'll update the question so that others users could understand the issue was with dj-rest_auth package.